# How does Android search for dependencies on GitHub?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, build.gradle

i want to implement a dependency from GitHub in my android project but it gives me this error

> Could not find com.github.RobertApikyan:SegmentedControl:1.2.0

I'm implementing this:

```
implementation 'com.github.RobertApikyan:SegmentedControl:1.2.0'
```

I think is the case because by build.gradle file doesn't search on GitHub for repos.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: *"How does Android search for dependencies on GitHub?"* - It doesn't!  It searches for them in your configured local and remote Maven repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workaround 1:

You can host a project release into mavenCentral using github, it is located at:

```
https://github.com/{user}/{repository}/packages?package_type=Maven
```

And in order to pull packages from it, add new repository in your build.gradle:

```
mavenCentral()
```

## Wordaround 2:

You can host your project's any branch or version at [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/)
and the great thing is that you don't need to setup anything it'll build your packages in their server and notify you. Your project will be located at:

```kotlin
https://jitpack.io/#{user}/{repository}
```

And in order to pull packages from it, add new repository in your build.gradle:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

Comment: Thank you. I should've read the repo again. It stands right there haha